# Unset an environment variable for one command

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I can run `ENV_VAR=value command` to run `command` with a specific value for `ENV_VAR`. What is the equivalent to unset `ENV_VAR` for `command`?

Comment: Aside: `command` is an unfortunate choice of placeholders, since there actually *is* a built-in command by that name. `mycommand` or `somecommand` or such might be a better habit to get in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I usually use `cmd` for that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Other than with the `-i` option, which wipes the whole environment, POSIX `env` doesn't provide any way to unset a variable.

However, with a few `env` implementations (including GNU's, `busybox`' and FreeBSD's at least), you can do:

```
env -u ENV_VAR command
```

Which would work at removing every instance of an `ENV_VAR` variable from the environment (note though that it doesn't work for the environment variable with an empty name (`env -u ''` either gives an error or is ineffective depending on the implementation even though all accept `env '=value'`, probably a limitation incurred by the `unsetenv()` C function which POSIX requires to return an error for the empty string, while there's no such limitation for `putenv()`)).

Portably (in POSIX shells), you can do:

```
(unset -v ENV_VAR; exec command)
```

(note that with some shells, using `exec` can change which `command` is run: runs the one in the filesystem instead of a function or builtin for instance (and would bypass `alias` expansion obviously), like `env` above. You'd want to omit it in those cases).

But that won't work for environment variables that have a name that is not mappable to a shell variable (note that some shells like `mksh` would strip those variables from the environment on startup anyway), or variables that have been marked read-only.

`-v` is for the Bourne shell and `bash` whose `unset` without `-v` could unset a `ENV_VAR` *function* if there was no *variable* by that name. Most other shells wouldn't unset functions unless you pass the `-f` option. (unlikely to make a difference in practice).

(Also beware of the bug/misfeature of `bash`/`mksh`/`yash` whose `unset`, under some circumstance may not unset the variable, but [reveal the variable in an outer scope](/a/382499))

If `perl` is available, you could do:

```
perl -e 'delete $ENV{shift@ARGV}; exec @ARGV or die$!' ENV_VAR command
```

Which will work even for the environment variable with an empty name.

Now all those won't work if you want to change an environment variable for a builtin or function and don't want them to run in a subshell, like in `bash`:

```
env -u LANG printf -v var %.3f 1.2 # would run /usr/bin/printf instead
(unset -v LANG; printf -v var %.3f 1.2) # changes to $var lost afterwards
```

(here unsetting LANG as a misguided approach at making sure `.` is used and understood as the decimal separator. It would be better to use `LC_ALL=C printf...` for that)

With some shells, you can instead create a local scope for the variable using a function:

```
without() {
  local "$1" # $1 variable declared as initially unset in bash¹
  shift
  "$@"
}
without LANG printf -v var %.3f 1.2
```

With `zsh`, you can also use an anonymous function:

```
(){local ENV_VAR; command}
```

That approach won't work in some shells (like the ones based on the Almquist shell), whose `local` don't declare the variable as initially unset (but inherit the value and attributes). In those, you can do `local ENV_VAR; unset ENV_VAR`, but don't do that in `mksh` or `yash` (`typeset` instead of `local` for that one) as that wouldn't work, the `unset` would only  be cancelling the `local`.

<sup>¹  Also beware that in `bash`, the local `ENV_VAR` (even though unset) would retain the *export* attribute. So if `command` was a function that assigns a value to `ENV_VAR`, the variable would be available in the environment of commands called afterwards. `unset ENV_VAR` would clear that attribute. Or you could use `local +x ENV_VAR` which would also ensure a clean slate (unless that variable has been declared read-only, but then there's nothing you can do about it in `bash`).</sup>

Comment: It's a separate question, but what the heck is an environment variable with an empty name and how would you ever use it - even for some sort of exploit? Wouldn't you have to write a program that reads the environment and specifically looks for something like this?

Comment: @Joe, try for instance `env '=foo' python -c 'import os; print os.environ[""]'`. I don't expect many people would want to set a variable like that.

Answer (score 11):

There’s no direct equivalent as far as I’m aware; you can use a subshell:

```
(unset ENV_VAR; exec command)
```

Comment: `(unset ENV_VAR; exec somecommand)` if you want to be equivalent to the original in efficiency (by consuming the subshell). As it is, this adds an extra fork.

Comment: @Charles indeed, although some shells do that automatically since `command` is the last command in the subshell invocation.

Comment: +1 because this way is simple to type for interactive use.  I use subshells for one-off changes to the shell environment for a one-liner instead of remembering that it's `env -u`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ENV_VAR= command`

This doesnt actually unset the variable, but it may be useful in many cases (shell scripts usually just use `test -n` to check if a variable is set):

```
$ export ENV_VAR=foo
$ mycommand
ENV_VAR: foo
$ ENV_VAR=bar mycommand
ENV_VAR: bar
$ ENV_VAR= mycommand
ENV_VAR:
```